# Why does my code only work in Google Colab but not on my local machine?

Tags: python, lambda, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I tried to run [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IPpwx4rX32rqHKpLz7dc8sOKspUa-YKO#scrollTo=RVJs4Bk8FjjO) code in Google Colab and it worked fine. If I run it on my home computer or connect Google Colab with my local computer it gives me Errors:

```
EOFError: Ran out of input

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

They appear because of this function:

```
test_loader = data.Dataloader(#Some unimportant parameters
collate_fn=lambda x: data_processing(x, 'valid'))
```

in

```
for i, _data in enumerate(test_loader):
```

I know that I cannot pickle lambda functions but it really works in Google Colab. But I need to run it on my local computer due to time and computing power reasons.

I tried it in PyCharm and JupyterNotebook as well as in Colab with local computer (via Jupyter) but none of them worked. The Error is also not because of the import versions, I tried also newer version, which worked in Google Colab.

Comment: Are your versions of Python the same on Colab and on your local computer? What are they?

Comment: I have Python 3.8.5 and Google Colab has 3.7.10. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Possibly. If you use data pickled with one version of Python, you may have difficulties when unpickling it with a different version of Python.

Comment: Also, it is likely that you have different package versions which might be as likely a cause.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try it :)

Comment: I can't download Python 3.7.10 (because it has only source release not exe) but nevertheless I installed all the packages and versions Colab (over 300) was using but it is still not running :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution for this problem:
The function should not be:

```
collate_fn=lambda x: data_processing(x, 'valid'))
```

it should be

```
collate_fn=data_processing
```

(Without parentheses and parameters; the "valid" parameter was redundant)